# See if HeaderContribution or ResourceReference exists in Wicket

Tags: wicket

When using `CSSPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(ResourceReference)` or `JavascriptPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(ResourceReference)` is there a way to see if the css or JavaScript file actually exist before calling add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `PackageResource`, the parent of `CSSPackageResource` and `JavascriptPackageResource` there is method `exists()` which is defined:

> **exists**
>
> public static boolean exists(Class scope,
>                                String   path,
>                                Locale   locale,
>                                String   style)
>
> Gets whether a resource for a given set of criteria exists.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **scope** - This argument will be used to get the class loader for loading the package resource, and to determine what package it is in. Typically this is the class in which you call this method
>
> **path** - The path to the resource
>
> **locale** - The locale of the resource
>
> **style** - The style of the resource
>
> **Returns**: true if a resource could be loaded, false otherwise

Just check out the [documentation](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/PackageResource.html#exists%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String%29)